# Olympiad question on functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, problem-solving

[image]

OK, I've tried solving the question, and here's what I've been able to do so far:

[image]

But I'm lost here.

What do I do now?

Comment: $f(1)+f(2)=2^2f(2)\implies f(2)=672$ and $f(1)+f(2)+f(3)=3^2f(3)$ .Continue this procedure.

Answer (score 3):

$$f(1)+\ldots+f(n)=n^2f(n)$$
$$f(1)+\ldots+f(n-1)=(n-1)^2f(n-1)$$

Subtract both equations and we get

$$f(n)=n^2f(n)-(n-1)^2f(n-1)$$
$$f(n)=\frac{n-1}{n+1}\cdot f(n-1)$$

which gives a recurrance equation.

Answer (score 1):

Hint : what is $n^2f(n)-(n-1)^2f(n-1)$ ?

In a more general case, when you have this kind of summations, always try to simplify terms. It can help.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @Vincent, we have 
$$f(n)=\frac{n-1}{n+1}f(n-1)$$
$$=\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{(n+1)n}f(n-2)$$
$$=...=2\frac{(n-1)!}{(n+1)!}f(1)$$

$$=2\frac{1}{n(n+1)}f(1)$$
$$\implies f(2016)=\frac{2}{2017}.$$

Comment: Sorry, may I ask where does the constant 2 come from? after expressing the right side into factorial form?

Comment: because $ f (2 )=1/3 f (1)= 2. 1/3.2 f (1) $ to complete denominator .

Comment: oh??? I overlook that one tnx :) Great Math :)